# TypeOrm don't make to connect to docker container postgress

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, typeorm, docker-network

I know, here a lot of similar question and I read a lot of that, but I still can't resolve that issue.

 So I have traditional docker-compose config with: posgresql, pgAdmin, nest.js app.
I run all services in docker compose, under docker network.

Db and pgAdmin is successful works, I may to connect from pgAdmin to postgres using container name 'db'.
But when I try to connect to my db from my nest application by TypeOrm, I was take that error:

`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26)`

When I start backend outside docker and connect by postgres container ip, all connected,
but in docker, container name / networkName / container ip not working, only one connection was without that error is with host:`host.docker.internal` , but then was ssl connection error, I was added url to connect pg `'postgresql://postgres:password@host.docker.internal:5435/postgres'` but then was again same connection error.

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - development.env
    environment:
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - db:/data/postgres
      - ./init-data.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-data.sh
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgresNet
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgAdmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - development.env
    volumes:
      - ./pgadmin/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
      - ./pgadmin/storage:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgresNet
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "python /pgadmin4/setup.py --load-servers /pgadmin4/servers.json --user ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL} --password ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}"]

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        DATABASE_URL: 'postgresql://postgres:password@db:5435/postgres'
        POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
        POSTGRES_HOST: 'db'
        POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'password'
        POSTGRES_DB: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - postgresNet

networks:
  postgresNet:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db:
  pgadmin:
```

*OrmConfig.ts*

```js
const configOrm: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'db',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'postgres',
  logging: true,
  synchronize: false,
  entities: [`${__dirname}/**/*.entity.{ts,js}`],
  migrations: [getMigrationDirectory()],
  subscribers: ['dist/subscriber/**/*.{ts,js}'],
  ssl: (isProd || isStage) && {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
};
```